# Finding substring of maximum length which satisfies the certain condition

Tags: string, substring, frequency

I have a string consisting of only two characters 'a' and 'b' I have to find the length of the maximum substring in which frequency of 'a' < frequency of 'b'. I am not certain how to approach it. I thought of trying to change it to maximum sum subarray by changing 'a' to -1 and 'b' to 1, but that didn't work.

Eg : 1 : baaabb

Ans = 3 as abb satisfies the given conditions.

Comment: This regex might be a good start: "a+b{2,}"

Comment: @I.Renk well this didn't work here. abababb it is matching only last abb of length 3 while the whole string satisfies the given conditions

Comment: Ah I see, my bad

Comment: @I.Renk so according to you this question can boil down to make regular expression {(a^m+b^n)*, m,n>= 0 and n > m}. I doubt whether this can be done via regex.

Comment: I say you should divide your problem into subproblems. Use a regex to find different valid combinations. Then sort by length and take the largest.

Comment: How should I divide this problem into subparts. I can only think of a basic brute force : for all substrings of the string check whether conditions satisfies, find out maximum length substring but unfortunately the string length can goes to 10^5 so this isn't feasible.